# Color Individual Lines with Gadfly

Tags: julia, gadfly

Is there a way to color each dataset?

There is a solution using DataFrames, but what about cases without them?

I tried this, but it has no effect:

```
using Gadfly

plot(
  layer(x=1:10, y=1:10, Stat.step, Geom.line),
  layer(x=1:10, y=2:11, Stat.step, Geom.line),
  color=["red", "green"]
)
```

Comment: how about `layer(x=1:10, y=1:10, Stat.step, Geom.line, Theme(default_color=colorant"green"))`

Comment: @GnimucK. Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Plotting should not be this painful.  Here's how you do it in [Plots](https://github.com/tbreloff/Plots.jl) using the Gadfly backend:

```
using Plots; gadfly(size=(400,300))
plot(rand(10,2), line = ([:red :green], :step))
```

[image]

Comment: This package is a great idea! Looking forward to using it.

Answer (score 2):

@GnimucK. comment shows how to do this when you're working interactively. That method runs into a few difficulties though when you want to pass a colour in as an argument to a function. In the general case where I have multiple lines where I want the colors to be chosen at run-time, I have a function that looks a bit like what follows:

```
using Compose, Gadfly
function my_plot_with_colors{T<:Number}(x::Vector{Vector{T}}, y::Vector{Vector{T}}, colorVec::Vector{ASCIIString})
    !(length(x) == length(y) == length(colorVec)) && error("Length mismatch in inputs")
    layerArr = Array(Vector{Layer}, length(x))
    for k = 1:length(x)
        layerArr[k] = layer(x=x[k], y=y[k], Geom.line, Theme(default_color=parse(Compose.Colorant, colourVec[k])))
    end
    return(plot(layerArr...))
end
```

where, if `length(x) = 3`, your input vector `colourVec` would look something like this: `["red", "green", "blue"]`.

Comment: Could work well with say candlesticks.  Will have to give it a try, thanks.

Comment: @BAR No probs. I spent a while working the above out for my own plotting module, so thought it worth sharing to save others the same pain.